# How to load a bitmap from file without using sample size?

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, bitmapfactory

I am making an image processing application, for that I want to be able to load and display full size image to give proper zoom in/out feature. When I do that I get memory exception, even when loading a single image.

My Question is, Is there any way to do that or I always have to use BitmapFactory.Options and give a sample size?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to disappoint you, but there is no way to do this without scaling. If you want to load the bitmap with the maximum resolution without out of memory exception, you can do the following.

Try to load the full resolution image, and if an exception occurs catch it and then increment the sample size and then do the same thing again. You can do this until you no longer get the out of memory exception. This way you get to load the bitmap with maximum resolution without crashing.

Comment: Although I am commenting late, still thanks Henry for the quick response.